# Subquery to return number for greater than equal to command

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return a list of items where `rental` is greater than the average `rental`. what is best way? Subquery does not seem to work with greater than operator:

```
select film, rental_rate from film
where rental_rate > (select (round(avg(rental_rate),2) as rentalrate from film)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course a subquery works with a `>` sign.  Your query should be fine, although I would leave out the rounding in the subquery:

```
select f.film, f.rental_rate
from film f 
where f.rental_rate > (select avg(f2.rental_rate) from film f2);
```

I made a few changes, but your original looked fine except for the extra `'('` before `round()`.